# Bazel- Does Java Test running support persistent workers?

Tags: java, bazel

Can you run java test targets with persistent workers (not remote workers)?
If so how does the worker handle the test state? Does it use separate class-loaders which are discarded after the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're actually experimenting with the feature in the [ExperimentalTestRunner](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/java_tools/junitrunner/java/com/google/testing/junit/runner/ExperimentalTestRunner.java), and you're right it uses a new classloader to load the classes of the test target which get discarded after each test.
While we haven't tested it yet for prime time it *can* be invoked in the current bazel (0.5.1) with the flags:

```
    --explicit_java_test_deps --experimental_testrunner --test_strategy=experimental_worker
```

Since this is still not launched, the best explanation of these flags can be found right now in the [change history](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/20c41d03ea798ced1e9f873e040a52b28974bb18).

Comment: Thanks! I saw your work on this area but somehow missed this commit. The commit message is very helpful. How experimental would you say this is between "probably will fail" to "soon to be formalized"?

Comment: The answer depends on what the tests are trying to do themselves. A lot of tests did pass but I know it currently does not handle the following scenarios:
1. When we try to load native libraries. AND
2. When the code under test assumes it's been loaded by the default System classloader, and does some operations based on the Clasloader/classpath we may get incorrect results.
<Sorry missed your reply earlier>

Comment: I think running the experimental persistent worker has changed.  `--test_strategy=experimental_worker` results in: `ERROR: 'experimental_worker' is an invalid value for test strategy. Valid values are: exclusive, standalone`